# Safari is not preventing the scrolling of <body style="overflow-y: hidden">

Tags: css, scroll, safari, overflow, mobile-safari

Here's the extremely simple HTML page

```
<body style="overflow-y: hidden">
  ...
</body>
```

The expected behavior of this page is: scrolling of a document is prevented because of `overflow-y: hidden`.

It works as expected (scrolling is prevented) everywhere except Safari.

**Live demo: https://spotted-chime.glitch.me/**

---

The question is: how to make Safari behave the same way as other browsers?

Comment: Funny enough, if instead of `overflow-y: hidden`, `overflow: hidden` will be set on body, Safari prevents vertical scrolling :)

Comment: You can try slapping "!important" behind overflow-y: hidden;

Comment: Apple claim they are supporting [`overflow`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-overflow). I would go in one of their shops and request a new device, which works properly. This one doesn't. Look! According to their own specs, it should. And I'd film the whole thing.

Comment: Changing `ontouchend` with `ontouchmove` will probably help.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `overflow: hidden` and it will work.

Alternatively, you can try using `position: fixed` on the `<body>` tag as well.

(NOTE: Using this approach, the `body` will scroll to the top as by default the `top: 0`.)

EDIT: For safari mobile devices, you need to use Javascript events. Explained in this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/2860486

Comment: `overflow: hidden` won't work for mobile devices (iOS), `position: fixed` on the `<body>` isn't acceptable because of the scrolling issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Position fixed is meant to create a div that stays in the same position  on the screen while the content behind it is scrolled down.

> **[fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)**
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no
>   space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned
>   relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport,
>   except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or
>   filter property set to something other than none (see the CSS
>   Transforms Spec), in which case that ancestor behaves as the
>   containing block. (Note that there are browser inconsistencies with
>   perspective and filter contributing to containing block formation.)
>   Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom,
>   and left.
>
> This value always creates a new stacking context. In printed
>   documents, the element is placed in the same position on every page.

Have you tried changing it to absolute?

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border: 5px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    

  </head>  
  <body>
    <div id="backdrop">
      
    </div>  
    <div>0%</div>
    <div>1%</div>
    <div>2%</div>
    <div>3%</div>
    <div>4%</div>
    <div>5%</div>
    <div>6%</div>
    <div>7%</div>
    <div>8%</div>
    <div>9%</div>
    <div>10%</div>
    <div>11%</div>
    <div>12%</div>
    <div>13%</div>
    <div>14%</div>
    <div>15%</div>
    <div>16%</div>
    <div>17%</div>
    <div>18%</div>
    <div>19%</div>
    <div>20%</div>
    <div>21%</div>
    <div>22%</div>
    <div>23%</div>
    <div>24%</div>
    <div>25%</div>
    <div>26%</div>
    <div>27%</div>
    <div>28%</div>
    <div>29%</div>
    <div>30%</div>
    <div>31%</div>
    <div>32%</div>
    <div>33%</div>
    <div>34%</div>
    <div>35%</div>
    <div>36%</div>
    <div>37%</div>
    <div>38%</div>
    <div>39%</div>
    <div>40%</div>
    <div>41%</div>
    <div>42%</div>
    <div>43%</div>
    <div>44%</div>
    <div>45%</div>
    <div>46%</div>
    <div>47%</div>
    <div>48%</div>
    <div>49%</div>
    <div>50%</div>
    <div>51%</div>
    <div>52%</div>
    <div>53%</div>
    <div>54%</div>
    <div>55%</div>
    <div>56%</div>
    <div>57%</div>
    <div>58%</div>
    <div>59%</div>
    <div>60%</div>
    <div>61%</div>
    <div>62%</div>
    <div>63%</div>
    <div>64%</div>
    <div>65%</div>
    <div>66%</div>
    <div>67%</div>
    <div>68%</div>
    <div>69%</div>
    <div>70%</div>
    <div>71%</div>
    <div>72%</div>
    <div>73%</div>
    <div>74%</div>
    <div>75%</div>
    <div>76%</div>
    <div>77%</div>
    <div>78%</div>
    <div>79%</div>
    <div>80%</div>
    <div>81%</div>
    <div>82%</div>
    <div>83%</div>
    <div>84%</div>
    <div>85%</div>
    <div>86%</div>
    <div>87%</div>
    <div>88%</div>
    <div>89%</div>
    <div>90%</div>
    <div>91%</div>
    <div>92%</div>
    <div>93%</div>
    <div>94%</div>
    <div>95%</div>
    <div>96%</div>
    <div>97%</div>
    <div>98%</div>
    <div>99%</div>
    <div>100%</div>

    <!-- include the Glitch button to show what the webpage is about and
          to make it easier for folks to view source and remix -->
    <div class="glitchButton" style="position:fixed;top:20px;right:20px;"></div>
    <script src="https://button.glitch.me/button.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <head>
    <style>
       .forSafari::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body style="overflow-y: hidden" class="forSafari">
         ...
  </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

just use "position: relative" or fixed it will resolve the problem